# How get all drawables res IDs from Animation-list?

Tags: android, android-drawable

If I have an animation drawable xml file (animation-list) which I can reference using `R.drawable.anim`, Is there a way I can get the all the `Drawable`s IDs in an array?

Basically I don't want to somehow load the xml file and get a list of all the `Drawable`s involved in that animation.

Here is the animation xml I am using

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/typer_step_1"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/typer_step_2"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/typer_step_3"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/typer_step_4"
        android:duration="50"/>

</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<string-array name="random_imgs">
    <item>@drawable/image1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image2</item>
    <item>@drawable/image3</item>
</string-array>
```

**in your activity**

```
   TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);
   //get resourceid by index
   imgs.getResourceId(i, -1);
   // or set you ImageView's resource to the id
   mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
   imgs.recycle();
```

Comment: But this is not getting it from the Animation-List xml file.. I want to read it from the animationList